# How can I establish relation between two tables

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Suppose I have a table subject in my database with data like:

```
subject_nam credit  gpa
chemistry       3.00    null
physics         3.00    null
```

And also suppose I have a student table. It will contain basic student information.

Now what relation do I need to have a copy of these subject for each student. gpa column would be different for every student.

Comment: A new table to connect the two would make sense. `Student_Subject` with columns like `Student_ID, Subject_Id, GPA, ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a database model such as:

```
create table subject (
  id int primary key not null,
  name varchar(50) not null,
  credits int not null
);

create table student (
  id int primary key not null,
  name varchar(50) not null
);

create table gpa_score (
  subject_id int not null,
  student_id int not null,
  score int not null,
  weighted_score int not null, -- added extra column as requested
  constraint pk_gpa primary key (subject_id, student_id),
  constraint fk1 foreign key (subject_id) references subject (id),
  constraint fk2 foreign key (student_id) references student (id)
);
```

Comment: Thanks. It was really helpfull.

One more question this model can I multiply crdit and gpa and save it in gpa_score

Comment: @MHSagar You could add an extra column `weighted_score` to store the math formula. To implement set the value you could: 1) Compute it in the app and set it while adding the row, 2) Use a trigger so the database will compute it for you.